# Make UIScrollView fill parent view with constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I am simply trying to add a scrollview in the view in Interface Builder and use constraints to have this scroll view fill its superview entirely

This is basically how it looks

[image]

**Why - when I click on the trailing or leading constraints - is the constant set to -20 instead of 0?**

**Why - when I run the app and inspect the view - can I see that the view has a width of 375 (running on iPhone 6) but the scrollview has a width of 383?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck `Constraint to margins` when you setting constraint to your scrollview. By default it is checked and it constraints from margin.

check the screenshot below,

[image]